# PHP form/MySQL values that contain commas have the comma and trailing zeros removed after updating another field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multi-screen form that potential clients can fill in their information for a loan.  There are 3 dropdown boxes for financial ranges in increments of 25,000.  There are also text boxes for personal information (name, email, etc.).

The data types for these 3 fields are varchar(45).

The form inserts the data into a MySQL table and the 3 financial fields are formatted correctly.  For example, if a potential clients selects the value for 150,000, the field in the database shows 150,000.

We can then open up our CRM to update these leads to enter more data or modify data.  If, for instance, we try to update a phone number or street address - not any of the financial fields, all 3 financial fields have their values missing the comma and 3 trailing zeros.

This is one of the fields in the edit form php file:

> <input class='' type="text" class="lamount" id="input-id-1"  style="width:100px;" value='' name="loan_amount">

This is how I am updating it:

> $loan_amount = $_POST(number_format(['loan_amount']));

With the binding:

> $stmt->bindParam(":loan_amount", $loan_amount);

Then, I update the values in the database.  All values that have been updated are updated correctly, except for the 3 values that are the financial values that were originally inserted by the forms.

Comment: Do var dump in your script and check the values posted. What format are the columns types  you are using?

Comment: I used echo and it displays with the comma and trailing zeros missing, and hadn't tried var_dump yet.  Varchar(45) is what i tried.  Could the data types be the issue?

Comment: For financial use decimal(9,2)

Comment: Don 't use varchar to store a decimal number. DB systems have different data types to use them, not only to use varchar

Comment: The financials never include decimal points.  They include only values in increments of 25,000

Comment: So show us the schema, all the code for this insert/update

Comment: @RiggsFolly there are 75 fields total in the table and code.  All of them except these 3 fields have no issues with updating.  I just did not want to take up so much space with that many lines of code here

Comment: Presentation logic like comma for thousands etc belong in the presentation layer, not the database.

Comment: I agree with you on that, but the client I'm working for insists on having the values in the database with the client,  Not my wish, but he is paying me to do it